# dj-rest-auth - Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, dj-rest-auth

I am using dj-rest-auth, and after following the documentation exactly how it is, when I go to the password/reset api endpoint, and enter my email, it return this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /api/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/
Django Version: 4.2.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Users/coding/Projects/django/user_template_api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  dj_rest_auth.views.PasswordResetView
Python Executable:  /Users/coding/Projects/django/user_template_api/.venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.12.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/coding/Projects/django/user_template_api/backend',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/coding/Projects/django/user_template_api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 18 Oct 2023 01:59:54 +0000
```

this is my accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import CustomUserViewSet
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', CustomUserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'), 
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

this is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-$!z5s1dryft$&tjajmulo+kb7^vi$mfujnzor$_zi(7qv9jxwj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    #3rd Party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    #local
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', 
            ],
        },
    },
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend" 

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [  
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

REST_AUTH = {
    'TOKEN_MODEL': None,
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'my-app-auth',
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'my-refresh-token',
}
```

I checked the dj-rest-auth urls.py in the virtual environment and the name of the password_reset_confirm is "rest_password_reset_confirm". Does this mean that there is a bug in the dj-rest-auth package?

```
from django.urls import path

from dj_rest_auth.app_settings import api_settings

from dj_rest_auth.views import (
    LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordChangeView, PasswordResetConfirmView,
    PasswordResetView, UserDetailsView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    # URLs that do not require a session or valid token
    path('password/reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset'),
    path('password/reset/confirm/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='rest_password_reset_confirm'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
    # URLs that require a user to be logged in with a valid session / token.
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='rest_logout'),
    path('user/', UserDetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),
    path('password/change/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='rest_password_change'),
]

if api_settings.USE_JWT:
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenVerifyView

    from dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth import get_refresh_view

    urlpatterns += [
        path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
        path('token/refresh/', get_refresh_view().as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reverse function is looking for 'password_reset_confirm'

However, the name given in your urls.py is '**rest**_password_reset_confirm'.  They don't match, so an error is raised.

They will need to match for the reverse lookup to be successful.

Currently on the dj-rest-auth [FAQ page](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) they note this is known behaviour, and recommend adding the following code:

````
    # this url is used to generate email content
    re_path(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,32})/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),```
````

Comment: Yes, but the urls.py that says 'rest_password_rest_confirm' is the dj-rest-auth's urls.py that was installed, so does that mean there is a bug in that package?

Comment: Oh, I see - it's all their code. I don't know about a bug, but it seems they know about it.  Check out number 2 on their FAQ page: https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html